# iOS 13 not getting VoIP Push token

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

I register delegate for `PKPushRegistry` in `AppDelegate` method `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` by following code:

```
let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
voipRegistry.delegate = self
voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
self.voipRegistry = voipRegistry
```

When I run app on iOS 12 everything works correctly - method `func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType)` is triggered, but in iOS 13 case this method is not triggered at all.

What I do wrong in iOS 13 case? May be I need add some additional code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what changed but after day everything is works - token is received, method `func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType)` is triggered.